# Matching date, excluding 0 from month

Tags: regex, regex-group

We have files named like the following:

d31_20210315-19232.sql.tar.gz
d31_20201215-19232.sql.tar.gz

Matching the year is easy:
`(?<=_)(?P<year>\d{4})`

matching the month without the 0 has me coming unstuck:
`(0(?P<month>[1-9]))|((?P<month>[1][1-9]))`
this isn't allowed but describes what I want to do.

Same with the day I want to ignore the 0 and match either 1-9 or 12-31 inside the group:
`(?P<day>`

I'm at the stage where I'm going to try and code around the regex capture to get the desired result, but its been bugging me I cannot get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this one:

```
(?<=_)(?P<year>\d{4})0?(?P<month>\d+)(?=\d\d-)0?(?P<day>\d+)
```

- `(?<=_)(?P<year>\d{4})` matching the year.
- `0?(?P<month>\d+)(?=\d\d-)` matching the month, ignores the `0` if there's any. Also makes sure after the group `month`, there are still 2 digits with a dash in front.
- `0?(?P<day>\d+)` matching the day, ignore the `0` if there's any.

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/MGZkTa/1/)

Comment: Works perfectly thank you. Really annoyed I didn't get this!